# Divergence theorem non continuously differentiable

Tags: electrostatics, charge, mathematics

In class we calculated the electric field in- and outside a charge distribution:
$$
\rho(r)=
\begin{cases}
\cos(r)+\frac{1}{r}\sin(r) &\text{if }r\leq R \\
0 &\text{if }r>R
\end{cases}
$$

We used the divergence theorem to calculate this. But as far as I know, this theorem only applies if $\rho$ is continuously differentiable. Why can we apply this then?

Comment: Your function $\rho$ is $C^\infty(\mathbb R^3\setminus S^2)$, and the two-sphere has zero measure, so everything works just fine. To be pedantic, you can consider the integral over $\mathbb R^3$ minus $B(R+\epsilon)-B(R-\epsilon)$, and take the limit $\epsilon\to0$.